# How to implement Excel vbA in C#

Tags: c#, excel, excel-2007, vba

Can you help me rewriting the following Excel VB code to C#?

```
Range("C9:E11").Select
Selection.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlCellValue, Operator:=xlEqual, _
    Formula1:="=1"
Selection.FormatConditions(Selection.FormatConditions.Count).SetFirstPriority
With Selection.FormatConditions(1).Interior
    .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
    .Color = 255
    .TintAndShade = 0
End With
Selection.FormatConditions(1).StopIfTrue = False
```

Comment: If you don't mind me asking, why? Also, are you having trouble with any particular aspect of the C# for this, or are you looking for help to get started? Thanks :)

Comment: This sounds like a homework question...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;
 ...
 object mis = Type.Missing;

 Excel.FormatCondition cond =
    (Excel.FormatCondition)range.FormatConditions.Add(Excel.XlFormatConditionType.xlCellValue,
    Excel.XlFormatConditionOperator.xlEqual, "=1",
    mis, mis, mis, mis, mis);
    cond.Interior.PatternColorIndex = Excel.Constants.xlAutomatic;
    cond.Interior.TintAndShade = 0;
    cond.Interior.Color = ColorTranslator.ToWin32(Color.White);
    cond.StopIfTrue = false;
```

Answer (score 5):

What you're looking for is Excel Automation. Pretty much this means using a set of COM objects provided by Excel to remote control Excel from another application.

Anything you can do with with VBA you can achieve with Automation (OK, almost anything).

If you google for "Excel Automation C#" you'll get lots of hits. [How to automate Microsoft Excel from Microsoft Visual C# .NET](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/302084) was the first returned to me, and looks like a good place to get started.

Hope this helps,